# What is the big $O_p$ of the product between a $O_p(a_n)$ term and a uniformly bounded function?

Tags: probability, convergence, asymptotics

Suppose $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \hat{\theta}_i^2 = O_p(a_n)$ and $||f(X)||_{\infty}$ is bounded.

What is the big $O_p$ of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{\theta}_i f(X_i))^2$?

The way I understand this is because $||f(X)||_{\infty}$ is bounded (i.e., uniformly bounded), then the square of $f(X)$ is bounded too. Therefore, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{\theta}_i f(X_i))^2$ should still be bounded in probability. But I'm not sure what exactly the $O_p$ is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F:=\|f(X)\|_\infty$, you have that
$$\left\vert\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{\theta}_i f(X_i))^2\right\vert \le F^2 \left\vert\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{\theta}_i)^2\right\vert $$
Hence, for any real number $M$ such that $\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{\theta}_i)^2\right)/a_n $ is smaller than $M$ with probability greater than $1-\varepsilon$, it follows that $\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{\theta}_if(X_i))^2\right)/a_n $ is smaller than $MF^2$ with probability greater than $1-\varepsilon$ as well.

In other terms, it follows from [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation#Big_O:_stochastic_boundedness) that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{\theta}_if(X_i))^2$ is $O_p(a_n)$ as well.